# Run Python Script from Batch File with hard coded user input

Tags: python, file, batch-file

I have a python application that will ask the user if he wants to regenerate a new database. This user input is needed for the app to proceed.

When this application is run from the batch file, I want that answer to automatically and always be `"Yes"` and proceed automatically.

How would I update my batch file so the application automatically proceeds with `"Yes"`?

Currently my batch file:

```
@echo off
C:\my_venv_path\python.exe "C:path_to_app\main.py"
```

Comment: It depends on the .py file. Does it have a command line option or other mechanism like a environment variable to do it? And if you own that .py file, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `piping` and `echo` to get the desired result:

```
@echo off
echo Yes | C:\my_venv_path\python.exe "C:path_to_app\main.py"
```

You can read more about script redirection [`here`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php).